# Unlikely ORA 0955 Error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I get this error ORA 0955 when running my batch (.BAT) file which runs another SQL file.

[image: Batch File]

Batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "SqlUserName="
set "SqlPassword="
set "SqlDatabase="
:Credentials
set /P "SqlUserName=Enter username: "
set /P "SqlPassword=Enter password: "
set /P "SqlDatabase=Enter database: "
@(
echo whenever sqlerror exit failure
echo connect %SqlUserName%/%SqlPassword%@%SqlDatabase%
echo @C:\Users\njediaz\Desktop\sql.sql
echo exit 
) | sqlplus.exe -s /nolog
if errorlevel 1 goto Credentials
echo About to exit.
timeout /t 30
endlocal
```

SQL.sql code

```
--conn cpi/cpi12345!@fgicrcm
--conn &&username@&&DBNAME

SET HEADING OFF;
SET ECHO OFF;
SET PAGES 999;
SET LONG 999999;
SET LONGCHUNKSIZE 999999;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET LINESIZE 500;

/****************/
/*BACKUP Scripts*/
/****************/

--Use SPOOL then set the filename and location of the scripts to be saved.--
--Use DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl and specifiy the OBJECT_TYPE, OBJECT_NAME and OWNER_NAME--

SPOOL C:\GeniisysUpdater\Backup\Scripts\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pks
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('PACKAGE_SPEC', 'GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG', 'CPI') FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF
HOST ECHO / >>  C:\GeniisysUpdater\Backup\Scripts\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pks

SPOOL C:\GeniisysUpdater\Backup\Scripts\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pkb
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('PACKAGE_BODY', 'GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG', 'CPI') FROM DUAL;
SPOOL OFF 
HOST ECHO / >> C:\GeniisysUpdater\Backup\Scripts\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pkb

/*********************/
/*INSTALL New Scripts*/
/*********************/

SPOOL C:\GeniisysUpdater\Install\Scripts\Logs\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG_pks.log
@C:\GeniisysUpdater\Install\Scripts\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pks
SPOOL OFF

SPOOL C:\GeniisysUpdater\Install\Scripts\Logs\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG_pkb.log
@C:\GeniisysUpdater\Install\Scripts\GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pkb
SPOOL OFF

/***************************/
/*RECOMPILE Invalid Scripts*/
/***************************/

SPOOL C:\GeniisysUpdater\Install\Scripts\Logs\recompile_scripts.log
@C:\GeniisysUpdater\Backup\rcpl.sql
SPOOL OFF

/***************************/
/*Check if batch is done*/
/***************************/

SPOOL C:\GeniisysUpdater\Install\Files\batchDone.log
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL /
SPOOL OFF

EXIT
```

I tried running each Database files (pks, pkb, sql) in TOAD and I didnt get any errors.

Here are my codes to the following scripts:

[GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pks](http://jpst.it/wuMt)

[GIAC_ORDER_OF_PAYTS_PKG.pkb](http://jpst.it/wuMw)

[rcpl.sql](http://jpst.it/wuMJ)

Comment: If you are re-executing the script, then make sure to have DROP statements before the CREATE to make the script re-executable. Another reason might be that you got a "/" after the statement, however you already ended the previous statement with a semi-colon. Thus re-executing the statement in buffer.

Comment: Should I remove the "/"? Or the semicolon?

Comment: Stick to one of the terminator. Semi-colon is used for a single statement, "/" is used for a block.

Comment: Can you show few lines of the code before and after the line the error occurs.

Comment: @OP, see Jon Heller's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with code before a comment with incorrect spacing.  For example, copy and paste this text into SQL*Plus:

```
create table only_execute_once(a number);
/***************************/
/*RECOMPILE Invalid Scripts*/
/***************************/
```

And the results look like this:

```
SQL>     create table only_execute_once(a number);

Table created.

SQL>     /***************************/
SQL>     /*RECOMPILE Invalid Scripts*/
    create table only_execute_once(a number)
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object


SQL>     /***************************/
SQL>
```

From the [SQL*Plus manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_five.htm#sthref425):

> You must enter a space after the slash-asterisk(/*) beginning a
>   comment.

Although it's documented I would still consider this a bug.  Most of the time those kinds of comments work.  The SQL*Plus parser has a few issues with slashes.

Comment: I don't think that is an issue. `SQL> SELECT 'before' FROM dual;

'BEFOR
------
before

SQL> /***************************/
SQL> /*RECOMPILE Invalid Scripts*/

'BEFOR
------
before

SQL> /***************************/
SQL> SELECT 'after' FROM dual;

'AFTE
-----
after

SQL>`

Comment: @LalitKumarB I added a better example.

Comment: Perfect! You nailed it. As I thought the culprit would be slash, however, didn't expect it to be the comments. +1

Comment: But as you can see on my SQL.sql code, there is always a space/linebreak between codes and comments.

Comment: @ladiesman1792 The problem is not the space between code and comments, it's the missing space *inside* your comment.  Your code is valid according to SQL and PL/SQL syntax, but not SQL*Plus rules.